# Help removing old weather stripping on exterior aluminum door

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

My exterior door weather stripping doesn't work very well any more (it's pretty drafty). The doors are glass doors with an aluminum frame. The weather stripping is made of some brush-like material.

I bought some [Wear-Resistant Natural Gum Foam Strips](https://www.mcmaster.com/catalog/129/4034/93625K54) and my plan was to pull off the old stuff and peel and stick the new stuff on.

I tried to pull the old stuff off with pliers and tore some of the brush out - it looks like it might be built-in or something; it's sticking out of some grid inside the doorframe.

What is this type of weather stripping called? Am I correct that it looks built-in? What's the appropriate way to replace this weather stripping with something new?

[image: picture of weather stripping]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **pile** weatherstrip. It is attached to a flat backing that has been inserted into a slot.

Replacement pile weatherstrip is available in myriad different sizes/types, i.e., width and thickness of backing strip to fit the slot, height of pile, width of pile, density of pile fibers, pile material (e.g., wool, nylon). A good window and door shop should have some replacement, sold by the roll or sometimes by the foot.

It's not super easy to replace because it usually involves removing the pane frame so you can slide out the old and re-insert the new. It sometimes requires disassembling the frame so you can get to it.

[image]
[image]